# UWP simple Databinding not working

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp

I have been following some training videos and created a simple app with UWP and C#, and using UWP Databinding, unfortunately passing data from a textbox to a class property just doesn't work. Nothing happens. No data is passed, no errors generated.

So my class(everything stripped to relevant code) is

```
 public class ChangeCalc
{
    public string GoodsCost { get; set; }
    public string Amountpaid { get; set; }
```

Under page is

```
 <Page.DataContext>
    <local:ChangeCalc />
</Page.DataContext>
```

Under my 2 TextBoxes I have

```
  <TextBox
            x:FieldModifier="public"
            Text="{Binding Amountpaid, Mode=TwoWay}"
            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

So it is all there.

If I just call it under the button Click event in the codebehind it works OK. Data passes, code runs.

```
  myChangeCalc.GoodsCost = txtCost.Text;
  myChangeCalc.Amountpaid = txtPaid.Text;
```

When is the databinding initiated? What event, if any, is missing?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you know that databinding is not working?

Comment: Did you implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Most likely your question is a duplicate of the many already on Stack Overflow that boil down to "I failed to implement property change notifications". But without a good [mcve] it's impossible to know for sure _what_ the problem is. Please improve the question if you want help.

Comment: There is nothing being passed through. yet with the click event to the same properties, it passes OK.

Comment: Peter, according to all I have read that is all I need to do. I am using the databinding in the Properties, and each step (of which there is only about 4) produce the same changes in the xaml.

Comment: silverfighter, you don't have to  implement INotifyPropertyChanged (what do I know I can't get it to work) The instructions say : Changes to TextBox.Text are sent to a two-way bound source when the TextBox loses focus, and not after every user keystroke.

Comment: For the sane people that wind up here, that did implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly, it's because the default databinding mode in UWP is `Mode=OneWay`, you *MUST* specify `Mode=TwoWay` if you want your models to be updated. -- Fun times!

Comment: @BrainSlugs83, not exactly, data binding in UWP, when use `Binding`, by default `Mode=OneWay`, but if we use `x:Bind`, by default `Mode=OneTime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is nothing being passed through. yet with the click event to the same properties, it passes OK.

This is because when you use data binding, you just give a data model as `DataContext` in where the property can be found to the `TextBox`, you didn't actually pass any real data to the `TextBox`. And when you use button click event, you create an instance "myChangeCalc" of this data model and pass a real data like "txtPaid.Text" to the property "Amountpaid" of this instance.

> silverfighter, you don't have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged (what do I know I can't get it to work) The instructions say : Changes to TextBox.Text are sent to a two-way bound source when the TextBox loses focus, and not after every user keystroke.

Yes, but this change is from binding target to binding source, if you want change from binding source to binding target here, you must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on the source object so that the source can report changes through events that the binding engine listens for.

So, as an example here:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:ChangeCals x:Name="ccData" Amountpaid="111" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" DataContext="{StaticResource ccData}">
    <TextBox
        x:FieldModifier="public"
        Text="{Binding Amountpaid, Mode=TwoWay}"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"  Height="50" />
</Grid>
```

You can create a instance of your data model in the page resources, and set this resource as the `DataContext` of Binding.

Another example:

```
<TextBox
    x:FieldModifier="public"
    Text="{Binding Amountpaid, Mode=TwoWay}"
    TextWrapping="Wrap"  />
```

code behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = myChangeCalc;
}

public ChangeCals myChangeCalc = new ChangeCals { Amountpaid = "111", GoodsCost = "222" };
```

Any way, the binding source should be an instance of your data model(ChangeCals class). Since you used {Binding} here, I didn't show sample of using {x:Bind}, if you want to learn more about {x:Bind}, you can refer to [{x:Bind} markup extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). For more info about binding and x:Bind, you can refer to [Data binding in depth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth).